# How to transform System Requirement Specification documents to class and functions?

Tags: class, oop, srs

i'm currently preparing the srs documents for a project , i wounder how these documents and flow charts are transformed to classes , packages and functions?

 any suggestion to books or tutorials that explain this transformation process ?

Comment: There's no "transformation"! Somebody has to write code!

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok  is there is any guidelines for translating these documents into classes and functions ?

Comment: Yes, here's one: create code that meets all of the requirements. What is it you think that computer programmers do?

Answer (score 0):

What you might looking for is called "Object Oriented Design". 
This generally describes the process of modeling classes and structures out of real world or business objects (described in your specification).
This is quite a wide topic, but as a good starting point I would recommend the book 
[Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X).

For some other suggestions see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162231/ooad-book-recommendation-from-theory-to-practice).